# Protect table from wrong data being inserted

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking

I have two tables

flats

```
   id - primary key
   title - text
```

flats_reservations

```
   id - primary key
   flat_id - foreign key to flats(id)
   creator_id - foreign key to users(id)
   is_reserved - boolean
   created_at - current_timestamp
```

If flats_reservations has these rows

```
id=1, flat_id=12, creator_id=5, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:00
id=2, flat_id=12, creator_id=5, is_reserved=0, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:05
id=3, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:10
```

Then **only** user with id=4 can remove reservation (e.g. insert following row (**is_reserved=0**)

```
id=4, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=0, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:10
```

No other user can make this. At any point of time only one user can `reserve` flat.

Can I use mysql transactions to ensure that two users at the same time can not `reserve` flat?

I want to be sure, that following rows can not be inserted at once

```
id=5, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:15
id=6, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:15
```

In application I use following queries in transactions

```
# transaction start
select is_reserved from flat_reservations where flat_id=12 order by created_at desc limit 1;
# if is_reserved == 0 or query returned 0 rows then
insert into `flat_reservations` (`flat_id`, `creator_id`, `is_reserved`) values (12, 4, 1)
# commit
```

Is there some way to lock table during execution of these two queries and *only* when flat_id=12?

Users must be able to `reserve` other flats (e.g., where id is not 12).

If it is not possible then should I lock the whole table for writing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php on website you can check if it is not reserved just before writing and return some text to user.

You could also remove is_reserved from this table and make flat_id UNIQUE. So if it will be added to this table, it will mean that it is reserved.

You can also try to write to this table only by using trigger with condition (if it is not reserved).